# Proof of Uniform Boundedness Theorem in Kreyszig question

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

> Let $(T_n)$ be a sequence of bounded linear operators $T_n : X \rightarrow Y$ from a Banach space $X$ into a normed space $Y$ such that $(\|T_nx\|)$ is bounded for every $x \in X$.  Then the sequence of the norms $\|T_n\|$ is bounded.
>
> Let $A_k = \{x : \|T_nx\| \le k\}$.  Then $A_k$ is closed.  This is true because if $x \in \bar A_k$ then there is a sequence $(x_j) \in A_k$ converging to $x$.  This means that for every fixed $n$ we have $\|T_nx_j\| \le k$ and obtain $\|T_nx\| \le k$ because $T_n$ is continuous and so is the norm.

How does $T_n$ and $\|.\|$ being continuous show that $\|T_nx\| \le k$?

Comment: Remember that limits commute with continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the limit of the inequality $\|T_n x_j\| \le k$ when $j\to +\infty$.